# How to send a file from Google Cloud Platform Kubernetes Pod to external FTP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ftp, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an issue when trying to upload a file using [PHP FTP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) from my website that is deployed on the GCP Kubernetes Engine. And when I try to upload it manually from the Pod terminal using the `ftp` command, it allows me to open the connection and login with the given username and password.

But, when I try to upload the file and even do the `ls` command to see the directory list, it is always stuck. There is no helpful error or any message as shown below.

[image: FTP Connect Screehot]

But then, when I try to cancel it, I get this message:
[image]

I have tried all of the above steps on my local computer and it's working. I can upload it to that FTP server. So, there is no issue with the FTP server.

Is there a way to trace what is the issue?

And what should I do so I can upload the file from GCP Kubernetes Pods?

Thanks

Comment: If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for the community or upvote if the answer has some useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An FTP server probably is configured correctly, but the problem is with authorizing users at login or you are behind a firewall that isn't allowing the incoming reverse connection from the ftp server to your client.

This error occurs mainly due to Invalid FTP Host, firewall restrictions , ISP restrictions  and you need  to configure FTP in [Passive mode](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html)

Below are the possible ways to check :

1. first check in the system allow to do ftp in the locally
   See if it is allowing then also
   check /var/adm/inetd.sec there is some entry for ftp
2. check the /var/log/messages log file on server

**getaddrinfo ‘Hostname_Is_Here’ error: Name or service not known
warning: unable to determine IP address of ‘host.domain.tld domain’**

This is because the FTP server cannot determine the IP address of the server by hostname.

3)) Try to PING Hostname  #ping hostname
If ping does not respond, you will have  to define the correct hostname in the configuration files as follows and restart network service.

/etc/hosts

/etc/sysconfig/network

/etc/init.d/network restart

Kindly follow this [doc](https://bobcares.com/blog/ftp-error-421-service-not-available/) and [solutions](https://community.hpe.com/t5/Networking/ftp-problem-421-service-no-available/td-p/3126898#.YvM5vytBy3A) which will help you in troubleshooting this issue.